# Pass the data to Json from C#

Tags: c#, json

Really new to JSON and webapi. I want to pass some data to JSON URL and get the data back as a c# object. so far what i can find online is below no much information I found or i am not reached. I don't know how to pass the value. 
"URL/importSet" what is the meaning here for importset.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL/importSet");

IWebProxy theProxy = request.Proxy;

if (theProxy != null)
{
    theProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
}

CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.CookieContainer = cookies;

// write the "Authorization" header
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "token-key001");
request.Method = "POST";
var data = new {"I try to copy paste the json data here what i mention down"}
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    Console.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

and my json data format is :

```
 {
    "BasicInformation": {
        "BranchName": "ABC",
        "DateFrom": "20180905",
        "DateTo": "20180905"
    },

    "Details": "",
    "Header": {
        "Company": "C001",
        "BranchCode": "ABC123"
    }
}
```

Any help will be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: You want to convert the result of `reader.ReadToEnd()` (which is the JSON you're showing) to a c# object?

Comment: Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-request-data-using-the-webrequest-class) article from MS Docs. It explains how to use `WebReqest` and answers the question of what is the meaning of `importSet` (i.e. it is the URI of the resource)

Comment: Do you want to convert JSON format data in C# and C# to JSON?

Comment: @Haytam i want to pass the json data to that URL , that URL to get a result to me but i have to pass my details. details format is that json.

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha , yes i want to pass the data to json and get back the some result as c#.

Comment: Visit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all support me. below is the code work for me, now I can get the response.

```html
try
            {
                string webAddr = "URL/ImportSet";

                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "TOKEN NO");
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = "{\"BasicInformation\":{\"BranchName\":\"Abc\",\"DateFrom\":\"20180905\",\"DateTo\":\"20180905\"},\"Details\":\"\",\"Header\":{\"Company\":\"C001\",\"BranchCode\":\"ABC123\"}}";

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    textBox1.Text = responseText.ToString();

                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to pass an object as json, you can use the package `Newtonsoft` available in the NuGet package manager.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

You'll use it as follow:

```
var data = new {
    BasicInformation = new {
        BranchName = "ABC",
        DateFrom = "20180905",
        DateTo = "20180905"
    },
    Details = "",
    Header = new {
        Company = "C001",
        BranchCode = "ABC123"
    }
};

var dataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

This gives:

```
{"BasicInformation":{"BranchName":"ABC","DateFrom":"20180905","DateTo":"20180905"},"Details":"","Header":{"Company":"C001","BranchCode":"ABC123"}}
```

Which you can then use in your request:

```
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataJson);
```

Now when you receive the result, just use `Deserialize` after creating a class that represents what you're receiving.

Comment: I would recommend using the `UTF8` encoding in place of `ASCII`.  Most web requests can handle UTF8 (and you can always specify that this is the format of your data).  This will allow passing of strings with non-ascii characters.

Comment: @Haytam : i should create the class for the information ? BranchName , datefrom and all? bcoz the data passing still showing me error that not refered.

Comment: You can, although the code I posted works if you want to just send/serialize.

Comment: I am getting 400 bad request error if I pass the value like what you suggested.

Comment: You'll need to look server-side for this :/

Answer (score 0):

Simple, You can use of `Newtonsoft` liberary for serialize and deserialize
Use: using Newtonsoft.Json;

like:

```
public T Deserialize()
    {
        var jsonData = "Your string JSON data";

        var objectJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData);

        return objectJSON;
    }

    public T Serialize()
    {
        var objectData = new Student();

        var objectData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectData);

        return objectData;
    }
```

For more Information see [`Newtonsoft`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm)

Or If you want to insert data in your `URL` and use of that in other pages, you have to create `QueryString` for more information see [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)

The HttpRequest class represents the request made to the server and has various properties associated with it, such as `QueryString`.

The ASP.NET run-time parses a request to the server and populates this information for you.

Read `HttpRequest` Properties for a list of all the potential properties that get populated on you behalf by ASP.NET.

Note: not all properties will be populated, for instance if your request has no query string, then the `QueryString` will be null/empty. So you should check to see if what you expect to be in the query string is actually there before using it like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["pID"]))
{
   // Query string value is there so now use it
   int thePID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["pID"]);
}
```

Comment: this is the line i have the first issue: "var jsonData = "Your string JSON data";" how i can pass the value in this line.

Comment: @NAJEEB Attention, In web Application, for send and recive data you have to serialize and deserialize. Imagin you have Student object that you want to send that as HTTP, you have to serialize that like my example, where is your object that you want to send that??

Comment: @NAJEEB Put your hardcode Instead of this: "new {"I try to copy paste the json data here what i mention down"}" in your code.

Comment: @NAJEEB Now if you copy that, you can send your data, and recive result of that. after that you can deserialize them to use.

Comment: @NAJEEB Did you copy that??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179462/discussion-between-amirreza-farahlagha-and-najeeb).

Comment: i pass the data like @Haytem solution. but not work for me. doubt is i should create the class for that or i can pass the value directly.

Comment: @NAJEEB Yeah! you can, but it is bad way! so do it.

Comment: @NAJEEB If my Asnwer was useful you can mark that. GoodLuck.

Comment: I did not get a solution yet.

Comment: @NAJEEB Try with classes.